# triggers that work without the WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database containing information about clubs, bands and their concerts. 2 most important 2 tables in my question look like that :

Band(Name, AmountOfMembers)

and

Concert(ClubName, ClubAdress, BandName, AmountOfMembers, Date)

I need to write a trigger that's going to fire when we update the Concert table with new information concerning a band (say we change the amount of members of band X), and update the Band table to reflect the changes.

So far I managed to write this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger ON Concert
INSTEAD OF UPDATE   
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE (AmountOfMembers)

    BEGIN

      UPDATE Band
      SET AmountOfMembers=(SELECT DISTINCT AmountOfMembers FROM inserted)
      WHERE Name=(SELECT DISTINCT BandName FROM inserted)


      UPDATE Concert
      SET AmountOfMembers=(SELECT DISTINCT AmountOfMembers FROM inserted)
      WHERE BandName=(SELECT DISTINCT BandName FROM inserted)
    END

END
```

This trigger works fine in most scenarios, however when testing it I realized it can't possibly work with the query : (and handling such type of query is a part of the assignment)

```
UPDATE Concert 
SET AmountOfMembers='50'
```

My other triggers that I wrote also fail to handle this scenario, but I skipped them here as they all look similar.

This is a part of a class assignment, (we're just starting sql so it's not that complicated, I know) so I'm not asking for a ready code for me to copy-paste, just some general tips on how should I approach this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are using the wrong database model or you are misunderstanding the question. A really important part of database models is "normalization", which (among other things) means: Do not duplicate data! Have a table `Concert(ClubName, ClubAdress, BandName, Date)`. If you need the number (or other details about the band), use `select * from concert join band on band.name =concert.bandname`. Then change the value (just) in `band`. The other (less likely option): `AmountOfMembers` in `band` means: "how many members of the band played (e.g. one was sick)". But then you don't need to update `band`.

Comment: A general rule of thumb: in an intro course for sql, you can probably write every query using a correct data model (e.g. "normalization") and standard sql syntax. This is actually hard enough! You (very likely) won't need triggers, unless your teacher explicitly tells you to use them.